# How to get the length of multidimensional struct arrays?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got a class that gets a 3-dimensional struct array in the constructor. For further calculations it also needs the length of each dimension.

a short example:

```
MyStruct*** mySt;
mySt = new MyStruct**[5]
mySt[0] = new MyStruct*[4]
mySt[0][0] = new MyStruct[3]
```

How can I get those values (5, 4, 3) back to save them in the new class without explicitely sending them to the constructor?

Comment: Unless you save the dimensions ahead of time you can't. Use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: Store them in constants

Comment: This was what I tried to avoid. Because if I save them I also have to pass them to the class making the code a bit messier. But it seems I will have to do that.

Comment: Does the array have to be allocated dynamically?

Comment: No. The array is, once created, not changed anymore.

Comment: I mean, do you have to allocate it with `new`? Or are the dimensions really this small and known at compile time? If you create your array like `MyStruct mySt[5][4][3]` then you can do what you are asking.

Comment: I cant exactly follow you, but I can describe how the arrays are created. There are 3 fix sizes for the dimensions eg. 32, 32, 64. Then in 3 loops the arrays are created like in sample code and filled with data. Those arrays are often created at runtime.

Comment: Your "3D array" doesn't have a size. The problem of making ND array this way is that, not all columns/rows/depths are necessarily the same length. Like the one you have created, all rows except [0,0,:] are of length 0.

Comment: In the way the array is created it is given that colums/rows/depths have to have the same size.  The short example is not representative, sorry.

Comment: This would be a good place to use `std::array`, since it knows its own size (in a zero-overhead manner). Also its superior to raw arrays in other ways as well.

Comment: @Eskalior You can do that but it's not enforced by the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get sizes from plain C++ arrays allocated with `new` and stored as pointers: there is no language construct that would let you retrieve an array size.

There are two options for how to deal with this situation:

- In C++ use a container that supports sizing - for example, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of vectors of vectors, or
- In C (or in C++, if you prefer to stay with arrays) construct a separate 3D array of sizes, and pass it along with the `mySt` array.

Comment: I don't think it is true that you cannot get sizes from "plain C++ arrays". That is exactly what [`std::extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) is for but you can't get the size of a plain C++ array if all you have is a pointer.

Comment: @ChrisDrew You are right, I should have clarified that I am talking about the situation in OP's post. Of course you can get the number of elements of an array-typed variable by using either `std::extent` or the old-way division of `sizeof`s.